# Aligning a subview in a Today widget extension

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, ios8

Apple recommend that we should:

`Align content with the widget’s title. When your widget content aligns with your title, people can easily scan the Today view for the widget they want. Respect the margins in the Today view, and restrain your content to the widget content area shown here.`

and provide the following image:

[image]

How do I programmatically, using autolayout, align a `UILabel`'s left edge with that of the Title? Or am I expected to just 'eyeball' it?

source: https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/PRERELEASE/IOS/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppExtensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH67-SW4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIEdgeInsets).

This will do it for you to align them.

Answer (score 0):

Just align it to your superviews left edge, that will be the widget content area.